# Sizing an SVG element according to png/jpeg image inside

Tags: svg

Trying to wrap my head around SVGs and displaying images. I asked a related question just a few hours ago but I seems to have managed to figure that part out, now I'm stuck with trying to figure out the relation between viewport, viewbox and the image tag inside it.

My first understanding of viewbox was that it was basically defining the coordination system. having it set to "0 0 100 100" meant "upper left corner is called 0,0 and 100,100 is the bottom right coordinate" then if you draw something like a rect you use 0-100 to reach the corners. Then you use css around it set the size you want on the container and all inside the SVG tag is scaled accordingly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="col-2" style="background: pink">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 bg-dark">
      <p>
        A bit of text
      </p>

      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="outline: 1px solid red" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <defs>
          <mask id="image-mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#F000FF" />
            <rect x="33" y="0" width="33" height="100" fill="white" />
          </mask>
        </defs>
       <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Panorama_Gendarmenmarkt-Berlin-Huntke-2008.jpg/640px-Panorama_Gendarmenmarkt-Berlin-Huntke-2008.jpg" mask="url(#image-mask)" /> 
      </svg>
      <p>
        Some more text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="background: orange">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That seems very wrong.

After tweaking and testing and poking around my current understanding is "if I want to display a non-vector image inside the SVG will I have to set the viewport and the image height/width to match the aspect ratio of the image, the numbers don't matter as long as the ratio is correct". So the image I have here is 640x170px. Normalising to width 100 the height is 26.56. So I set viewport to 0 0 100 26.56 and image width/height to 100 and 26.56 respectively:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="col-2" style="background: pink">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 bg-dark">
      <p>
        A bit of text
      </p>

      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 26.56" style="outline: 1px solid red" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <defs>
          <mask id="image-mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#F000FF" />
            <rect x="33" y="0" width="33" height="100" fill="white" />
          </mask>
        </defs>
       <image width="100" height="26.56" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Panorama_Gendarmenmarkt-Berlin-Huntke-2008.jpg/640px-Panorama_Gendarmenmarkt-Berlin-Huntke-2008.jpg" mask="url(#image-mask)" /> 
      </svg>
      <p>
        Some more text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="background: orange">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That seems to work, and it works for the commented out image as well when I adjust the numbers to fit it's aspect ratio of 100x66.56. I haven't really been able to find much info when it comes to the viewBox and images so my worry is that I'm just lucky and guessed something which works for two examples.

So the answers I'm looking for are:

- Are my assumptions correct?
- Does this mean that when I want to be able to show different aspect ratios of images do I have to adjust the viewport and the image width/height with javascript for each image?
- Is there any more efficient way of solving this? Like "width: 100%; Height: auto;" and make it wrap all aspect rations of images?

Comment: Given this viewBox="0 0 100 100" 0 0 represent the position (x,y) while 100 100 is the width and the height

Comment: @enxaneta but that's not the case for raster images, is it? Or at least that doesn't explain the first behaviour to me where the SVG red frame is a lot larger than the image even though both have h/w set to 100?